# Let users write to /var/www via ftp on debian running vsftpd

Tags: linux, ftp, sftp, vsftpd

One of our dev boxes runs debian and VSFTPD, and I would like to allow a few select users to write to `/var/www/testsite` and its sub directories.

They can browse to `/var/www` via a symlink in their home directories, but they can't write. It doesn't matter if it's using FTP or SFTP.

Any ideas? I find this problem difficult to google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are your permissions on /var/www/ and /var/www/testsite/ ?

My suggestion is to give /var/www/testsite/ a group such as testsiteGroup, make sure /var/www/testsite has rw permissions for group and then add the users to group testsiteGroup.

```
chgrp -R testsiteGroup /var/www/testsite/ 
chmod g+w /var/www/testsite/ 
usermod -a -G testsiteGroup # this wil be done for each user, and the -a is critical 
                            # the -a appends group to users groups, without -a you will
                            # be replacing the users groups with the one listed
```

Comment: No problem glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you use full authentication through SFTP (you should, for accounting) then vsftpd will use user's permissions to modify files.

Because of this there are two solutions:

- add users to group under which the web server is running (usually `www-data` or `www`)
- use ACLs and add default ACLs to directories in `/var/www`, this is much more fine-grained, but the partition needs to be mounted with `acl` flag

If you use anonymous access or FTP (which is by nature insecure), I'd strongly suggest going the second route.